# TFS 2015 Build vNext: cURL-FTP-Upload buggy or difficult to use

Tags: tfs, build, ftp, tfs-2015

In my vNext-build-definition I added a new build step: "**cURL Upload Files**".
 After a little while playing around with the syntax of the URL and optional arguments I finally accomplished it to reach my sftp-server in the right target folder - the connection works so far.
But when cURL tries to start the upload the log simply says:

```
curl: Can't open 'my-Subfolder/Another Subfolder/myfile.txt'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Unexpected exitcode 26 returned by tool curl.exe
```

With "buggy" I mean the way of selecting files in the definition of the build step without any assistance for the user: 
Try 1:
I can easily select files over the "..."-button - I can browse the folder-structure of my repository and select a file. Feels very normal. The folder is then written into the textbox "Files" - but without double-quotes although it contains spaces... This runs into an error because cURL does expectedly not understand the folder Name.
Try 2:
Then I added the double-quotes by myself, but still I get the error above.
Try 3:
Then I tried the syntax `**/myfile.txt`
Ahaa, this actually works!!... but this uploads all files in all folders that are named myfile.txt (the log tells me something interesting: curl is called by using another syntax with curly brackets: {"complete-path/to/my/filename"})

just in case somebody of the tfs-dev-team reads this: Another senseless link is "More Information" at the bottom of the step definition. It leads to a topic "Deploy: Azure PowerShell" - that has nothing to do with FTP-Uploads and it´s content is just "This topic hasn't been written yet.."  :-(

**So, I ended up now with the following possibilities**:
**1.** Use the syntax `**/filename` (if you can live with the drawback that all files in all subfolders of the repo with the same filename will be uploaded, so better keep your filenames unique!)
**2.** Use another build step before and copy or move the file into the root folder of the repo, in order to use the file name only in the "Files"-TextBox without path information.
**3.** Forget cURL-build-steps: Use WinSCP with a temporary script and run it with a batch-script-step(http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)  :-)

(The above mentioned syntax with curly brackets is useless for me because it forces me to have the whole path on the build agent included, I cannot use a relative path within my repo.)

Any better ideas?

Comment: I have experienced some issues with other VSO agent tasks as well. You should file all these issues on the vso-agent-tasks GitHub page so Microsoft can improve them. https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/cURLUploader

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario on my side with TFS 2015 update1 + curl 7.47.0:

1. If the folder contains spaces, like `Another Subfolder` in your scenario, curl can't recognize it, we'll get error:  `curl: Can't open 'C:/agent/_work/xx/s/Another'!`
2. If we use syntax **/myfile.txt, we'll get all files in workspace that are named myfile.txt.

But if we put the files under the folder whose name doesn't contain spaces, we won't get the error `curl: Can't open 'C:/agent/_work/xx/s/Another'!`, so you may consider create a new folder like `AnotherSubfolder` and put the files need to be copied under this folder, then you can use the whole path.

Comment: I have a similar issue where the files I must copy include some folder with spaces in their names.
Unfortunately I cannot rename them, since they are inside app.publish folder and contain clickonce deployment files. 
In this case, how to make it work?